# Type method appears to call private functions in an out-of-sync manner

Tags: f#

I'm taking my first steps with F# by porting over an interpreter I wrote in a different language. I made the following code really generic to get a minimal, reproducible example (so it might look nonsensical). I have a type method `this.Process` that calls a private `scan` function before calling the private `cleanupProcess1` function (which starts various "cleanup" tasks). For some reason, the cleanup functions get called while `scan` is still executing.

```ml
type SomeClass() =
    let mutable charSeq = Seq.empty
    let mutable chars = Array.empty
    let mutable currentIndex = 0

    let cleanupProcess2 () = printfn "called `cleanupProcess2`"

    let cleanupProcess1 () =
        printfn "called `cleanupProcess1`"
        cleanupProcess2 ()

    let next () =
        currentIndex <- currentIndex + 1

        try
            Some(chars[currentIndex - 1])
        with :? System.IndexOutOfRangeException ->
            None

    let scan () =
        printfn "called `scan`"

        let rec advance c =
            seq {
                printf "called `advance`... "

                match c with
                | Some(c) ->
                    printfn $"{c}"
                    yield c
                    yield! advance (next ())
                | None ->
                    printfn "(`advance` complete)"
                    ()
            }

        printfn "(before calling `advance`)"
        charSeq <- advance (next ())

    member this.Process(s: string) =
        printfn "called `this.Process`"
        chars <- s.ToCharArray()
        scan ()            // this contains `advance`...
        cleanupProcess1 () // ...and this executes before the above `scan`/`advance` completes?

        printfn $"{charSeq |> Array.ofSeq |> System.String}"


let someClass = SomeClass()

someClass.Process("foobarbaz")
```

Running that code should produce the following output:

```bash
called `this.Process`
called `scan`
(before calling `advance`)
called `cleanupProcess1`  # <--- why are these two being called early here?
called `cleanupProcess2`  # <---
called `advance`... f
called `advance`... o
called `advance`... o
called `advance`... b
called `advance`... a
called `advance`... r
called `advance`... b
called `advance`... a
called `advance`... z
called `advance`... (`advance` complete)

                          # <--- instead of being called after `advance` completes here?
                          # <---

foobarbaz
```

Everything compiles without any warnings. The sequence inside of `scan`/`advance` eventually gets built, but not before the cleanup functions are called. I expected them to be called *after* since the call to `cleanupProcess1` appears after the call to `scan`/`advance` inside of `this.Process`. This seems like some sort of async issue, but I'm not using `async {}` anywhere so I don't know if something somewhere needs to be "awaited" somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

F# sequences (`seq`) are lazy, which means that `advance` returns immediately and the contents of the sequence are computed later, on demand. In your case, it's the call to `Array.ofSeq` that forces the evaluation, but that only happens after your cleanup code has run. If you're familiar with C#, this is the same behavior as [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://brianreiter.org/2011/01/14/ienumerable-is-lazy-and-thats-cool/), and, in fact, `seq` is implemented via `IEnumerable<T>` under the covers. Note that lazy evaluation is *not* the same as async evaluation. There's nothing asynchronous about your code.

In order to compute the sequence eagerly, you can use an array instead:

```ml
        let rec advance c =
            [|
                printf "called `advance`... "

                match c with
                | Some(c) ->
                    printfn $"{c}"
                    yield c
                    yield! advance (next ())
                | None ->
                    printfn "(`advance` complete)"
                    ()
            |]
```

Resulting output:

```
calling `this.Process`
calling `scan`
(before calling `advance`)
called `advance`... f
called `advance`... o
called `advance`... o
called `advance`... b
called `advance`... a
called `advance`... r
called `advance`... b
called `advance`... a
called `advance`... z
called `advance`... (`advance` complete)
calling `cleanupProcess1`
calling `cleanupProcess2`
foobarbaz
```

Comment: Didn't realize you had already posted an answer, I'll delete mine.

Comment: In fact, `seq<T>` isn't just implemented via `IEnumerable<T>`; it's a simple alias for `IEnumerable<T>`.